# ¿Cómo obtener un objeto hidratado con campos calculados con ResultSetMapping?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine2

Estoy rellenando una instancia de una clase, con `ResulSetMapping` de la siguiente forma:

```
...
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;

$rsm->addEntityResult(Com\Entity\EntityBase::class, 'course');
$rsm->addFieldResult('course', 'id_course', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('course', 'name', 'name');
//$rsm->addScalarResult('has_preview_privileges', 'hasPreviewPrivileges');        

$query = $em->createNativeQuery("SELECT id_course,name,IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM....),false,true) AS has_preview_privileges FROM course AS course where id_parent=?", $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, 123);
$courses = $query->getResult();
...
```

(EntityBase es abstracta y de ella derivan otras, con un discriminador por uno de los campos, pero para el caso con la parte puesta espero que se puede entender mi duda... )

El tema es que quiero añadir el valor del campo "calculado" `has_preview_privileges`  en un atributo de la clase `Com\Entity\EntityBase::class`, he probado de diferentes formas y no doy con el clavo... (`has_preview_privileges`  no existe en la tabla, la propiedad correspondiente en la clase es `hasPreviewPrivileges`)

Una de las pruebas que hice ha sido:

```
$rsm->addScalarResult('has_preview_privileges', 'hasPreviewPrivileges');
```

Pero con esto consigo que el `$query->getResult()` me devuelva un array con el objeto hidratado pero sin añadir el valor de `hasPreviewPrivileges`, el hasPreviewPrivileges me lo pone aparte en el array. Es decir me devuelve el objeto y este atributo por separado (en un elemento del array).

```
$courses => 
         [0] => 
                 [ 
                   [0] => Objeto Hidratado correspondiente, 
                   [has_preview_privileges]=> "1" 
                 ]
```

Y lo que busco es que lo introduzca en el objeto, no que me lo dé por separado, no sé si me explico.

Se agradece cualquier aportación, gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente la solución ha pasado por utilizar el addScalar result y crear una clase que manejara el resultado ("Custom Hydrator") y utilizarlo en el getResult :

```
...
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('CustomHydrator', 'MyProject\Hydrators\CustomHydrator');    
....
$entities = $query->getResult('CustomHydrator');
```

Esa clase "hidratante" debe extender \Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator, y sobreescribir la función hydrateRowData(array $row, array &$result), en donde se se maneja la instancia rellenando los nuevos valores que se reciben através del parámetro $result.

```
protected function hydrateRowData(array $row, array &$result) {
   parent::hydrateRowData($row, $result);
   $key = count($result) - 1;
   foreach($result[$key] as $entityBaseOrScalar){
     $entityBaseOrScalar->setHasPreviewPrivilege($result[$key]["has_preview_privilege"]);
....
```

( No es como lo esperaba, pero a mi me sirve, al menos por el momento )